# What's the differences between libnfc to nfcpy?

Tags: open-source, nfc

I want to know what is the main differences between libnfc to nfcpy. i know that:

`libnfc` its an Open source library that allows you to communicate with NFC devices. `libnfc` is the first free NFC SDK and Programmers API released under the GNU Lesser General Public License. It provides complete transparency and royalty-free use for everyone.

`nfcpy` its the same like libnfc but using`Python` programming language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nfcpy` is aimed at implementing the NFC Forum specifications. This means that it has extensive support for NDEF message read and write on the various NFC Forum Tag Types, NDEF message exchange between peer-to-peer NFC devices and support for NFC connection handover.

`libnfc`, on the other hand, is a much more low-level library. It provides support for ISO 14443 contactless operation, including proprietary (and not supported by the NFC Forum) protocols such MIFARE Classic. You can use it to do ISO 7816-4 APDU communication (of which the NFC Forum Type 4 Tag supports a small subset). There are other libraries available which build support for NFC Forum specifications on top of `libnfc`, but also libraries that implement support for specific contactles cards such as MIFARE DESFire and MIFARE Ultralight C or that allow you to do card emulation using some contactless readers.